# Looping through metafields in shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

I need to display `n` number of images for a product in shopify.

I have stored number of images in a metafields and created a loop for it.

Then each image's name is stored in a metafield, which i am trying to get with help of loop.

```
{% assign earrings = product.metafields.earrings %}

{% for i in (1..earrings.total-earrings) %}
  {% assign earring = 'product.metafields.earring-' | append:i %}
  {{ earring.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

This loop is giving me values for `earring` like:
product.metafields.earring-1
product.metafields.earring-2

but when i am trying to read value of metafield `earring.name`, i am not getting any output. I think because `product.metafields.earring-1` is a string.

Is there any possible way to loop through metafields like this and get values?

Comment: Little question: why are you using metafield instead of product images?

Comment: Its because of complexity of design and required effect on product images.

Comment: @AlokJain.. Unless you are storing the images outside Shopify's CDN, @Alice's question is spot on. Shopify's CDN has added advantages. You can always configure the images loop. Secondly, you need only use one metafield to store all image or single type of data. Added them as a string separated by an distinct character. Then use `| split: ` usage to create and array and loop it. Reduces server load.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just in case it's helpful for someone.

Here's the updated code:

```
{% assign earrings = product.metafields.earrings %}

{% for i in (1..earrings.total-earrings) %}
  {% assign dummy = 'earring-' | append:i %}
  {% assign earring = product.metafields[dummy] %}
  {{ earring.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

So the simple way to loop through all the metafields is here:

CONDITIONS To loop through metafields, you should keep the same namespace, by default Shopify sets "custom" namespace to all metafields. You can keep anything while creating a metafield. Let's assume we will loop through all the metafields with the namespace added as "option", so we have `product.metafields.option.KEY`.

```
{% for metafield in product.metafields.option %}
 {% assign key = metafield[0] %}
 {% assign type = product.metafields.option[key].type %}

<!--// Now you got the meta-field's KEY & TYPE, handle it according to its access syntax; for example below, I am printing text of type text-multiline(list.single_line_text_field) meta-field values -->

 {% assign values = product.metafields.option[key].value %}
  {% for value in values %}
   {{ value }}
  {% endfor %}

 {% endfor %}
```